# ANGULAR: Inject Another Function after unsubscribing from Timer Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ionic3

I am creating an exam app so when time is up i needed a view controller to pop to tell the user he has exceeded his time and take him/her to a results page!!

But after unsubscribing from the timer, my function gets into a loop!!!

Please, i need help with this..

My codes below!

```
minutesDisplay: number = 0;
hoursDisplay: number = 0;
secondsDisplay: number = 0;

sub: Subscription;

showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

      subTitle: 'Ooops, Time Up! ',
    });
    alert.present();
    this.activity.openModal();
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.startTimer();
}

public ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.minutesDisplay == 1){
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    return true;

}

private startTimer() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(1, 1000);
    this.sub = timer.subscribe(
        t => {
            this.ticks = t;
            this.secondsDisplay = this.getSeconds(this.ticks);
            this.minutesDisplay = this.getMinutes(this.ticks);
            this.hoursDisplay = this.getHours(this.ticks);
            this.ngOnDestroy();
        }
    ); 
    this.showAlert();
 }
```

Comment: Could you set a plunker, please?How do you see the loop? The alert shows all the time?

Comment: Yes, a plunker would be very helpful here. Otherwise we are just guessing at syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this ... but you could try the following:

```
public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();  // Stop the timer if the user navigates elsewhere
}

private startTimer() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(1, 1000);
    this.sub = timer.subscribe(
        t => {
            this.ticks = t;
            this.secondsDisplay = this.getSeconds(this.ticks);
            this.minutesDisplay = this.getMinutes(this.ticks);
            this.hoursDisplay = this.getHours(this.ticks);
            if (this.minutesDisplay == 1){
               this.sub.unsubscribe();  // Stop the timer when time is up.
               this.showAlert();        // Show the alert now
            }
        }
    ); 
 }
```

Comment: I was thinking of the same :)

Comment: @DeborahK still returning same loop

Comment: You'll really need to provide a plunker for us to better examine how this is working. Go to this site: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue Drop down the list from the big green New button and select 'Angular'. Then add your code to the generated files. If you can demonstrate the issue there ... we can work with the code to resolve it.

Comment: Also ... will `this.minutesDisplay` ever be 1? What does your `getMinutes` method do?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/qk2c9nr6dBn2jWeaVf8d? thats the link to the code, you get to see what my getMInutes function does!!!

Comment: Wonderfully enough, i noticed when i copied this same plnkr code on my code editor and ran it on chrome, immediately the condition was met, console.log ran 40 times, i guess thats why i was in a loop! i just need the command to run once

Comment: No i havent as long as console.log loops 40 times, i think i have just understood why i was caught in that loop but i cant get out... It should only console.log once provided the limit time is reached

Comment: If you know a better way of putting a timer that performs an event when a certain time is reached, would be appreciated would just discard this observables method

Comment: I get `Invalid regular expression: missing /` when I try to run the plunker... I was able to fix this ... but I'm not getting any messages logged to the console.

Comment: I made the changes as I had recommended and it works fine. Not sure why those changes weren't working for you. Revised plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/JUDp8kGjaQ7vd0fbkGtE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.timer(1, 1000)
  .map(t=>this.getMinutes(t) === 1) // Observable<tick> -> Observable<boolean>
  .first(istimeUp => istimeUp) // take first Observable<true>
  .subscribe(()=>this.showAlert())
```